# Create Source-Destinations data frame using recursion in R

Tags: r, recursion

My data frame has only 4 columns: RoadName, Product, Source and Destination, which represents a way (RoadName) to take a product from point1 to point2.
However, point1 and point2 are not necessarily the "initial point" nor "final destination". The Destination in one register can be the Source in another register. I need to list, for every product, all full possible paths from the first point to the last point.

I've defined that the first points are the ones that I can not find as a destination. So, for each of their destinations, I check if it is a source to another destination, if it is true, I check if this destination is a source to another destination..... and so on...

Different sources can have the same destination and, what is even harder, a previous source became a destination again, after a few steps. For example, my dataframe has the following registers:

```
Case  RoadName   Product     Source     Dest
99999   R1         Prod1     Point1     Point2
99999   R2         Prod1     Point2     Point3
99999   R3         Prod1     Point2     Point4
99999   R4         Prod1     Point3     Point4
99999   R5         Prod1     Point3     Point2
```

Which means:Point1 sends to Point2, which can sends to Point3 and Point4. Point3 sends to Point4 and Point2 again (using other RoadNames or not). This would result in an infinite loop, right?)

For this small example, I would like to end up with the following rows ("dbPathWay" in the source code):

```
Case    Prod      1          2         3       4
99999   Prod1   Point1    Point2    Point3    Point4
99999   Prod1   Point1    Point2    Point3    Point2
99999   Prod1   Point1    Point2    Point4
```

I don't need to show the RoadName, but I can use it if it helps.

I was trying to solve using recursive function in R, but I'm having a really bad time with that. I've used [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/) as reference to build the algorithm (in this example, final destination is a parameter. I don't know my final destination. I break the search when the source does not have destination).
However, in my code, dbPathWay returns empty and I'm not able to debug inside the function to know what is happening.

The main script is just a loop trough the products. Trying to avoid big code, I'm using only one case and product as example

```
require("dplyr")
require("plyr")

dbProdDest <- data.frame(Case=c(99999,99999,99999,99999,99999), RoadName = c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5"), Product=c("Prod1","Prod1","Prod1","Prod1","Prod1"), Source = c("Point1","Point2","Point2","Point3","Point3"), Dest=c("Point2","Point3","Point4","Point4","Point1"))

dbPathWay <- data.frame()
dbPathWay <- NULL  #data frame to save all possible paths. Repre
dbProdDest <- data.frame()
    
#Find sources that are not destinations (initial points)
dbSources <-  (dbProdDest[!(dbProdDest$Source %in% dbProdDest$Dest),])
   
for (iSource in unique(dbSources$Sources)){
  
 # Initialize a list to be used to append every step on the pathway
  newRowPathWay <- list("Case" = 99999, "Product" = "Prod1")
      
  iNewSource <- iSource
  #Recursive part
   GetDestinRecursive(dbProdDest, iNewSource, newRowPathWay, dbPathWay)
      
} # end
```

I though the recursive function should receive the source and the original data frame with all source-destination for a product. For those destinations which are sources, the newRowPathWay list is incremented with the name of the destination and the recursion is called. For every destination, I have to check if it is already a source and, in this case, I consider it as a final destination (Point1 as 4 in the example). For those destinations which are not new sources, the newRowPathWay binds with the data frame dbPathWay.

```
GetDestinRecursive <- function(dbProdDest, iNewSource,  newRowPathWay, dbPathWay){
  countDest <- as.character(length(newRowRoteiro)-1)
  newRowPathWay[[countDest]] <- iNewSource
  
  dbNewDest <- dbProdDest[dbProdDest$Source == iNewSource,]
  
  #If there is no new destinations to iNewSource, so iNewSource is an end
  if (is.null(dbNewDest) ){
    #Append RowPathWay in dbPathWaty
    dfRow <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(newRowPathWay), ncol = length(newRowPathWay), byrow=F),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    dbPathWay <- rbind.fill(dbPathWay , dfRow )
    return(dbPathWay)
  } else{
    #For each new destination, check if it is already a vertice in the pathway. If it is true, break the loop. Otherwise, call recursion
    for (iDest in dbNewDest$Dest){
      if (iDest %in% newRowPathWay){
        dfRow <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(newRowPathWay), ncol = length(newRowPathWay), byrow=F),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
        dbPathWay <- rbind.fill(dbPathWay , dfRow )  
        return(dbPathWay )
      } else
      {
        return(GetDestinRecursive(dbProdDest, iDest, newRowPathWay, dbPathWay ))
      } #end if iDest
    } # end for iDest
  } # end if is.null
  
} #end GetDestinRecursive
```

I appreciate any help to make this recursive function works and/or to be able to debug it (I've tried use browser() at the begin of the code but it didn't work and I also tried to click on "Source" button but, it didn't do a step by step debug inside the loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just to check: Do you have an outer loop through products that makes sure dbProdDest holds only 1 product? This is necessary, as Point1 is not destination for Prod1, but can be for Prod2.

I changed the code to work on example you gave, haven't tested it throughly

Changes I made to code:

1. Example data frame dbProdDest. The last Dest value was changed from Point1 to Point2 as in example you gave. Otherwise there was no source that is not destination. 
   This is probably the reason why browser() didn't work. It never got into function.
2. I deleted rows:

   ```
   dbPathWay <- NULL  #data frame to save all possible paths
   dbProdDest <- data.frame()
   ```

dbPathWay was defined as data.frame before and the other one cleard the example data

So the first part looks like this:

```
dbProdDest <- data.frame(Case=c(99999,99999,99999,99999,99999), RoadName = c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5"), Product=c("Prod1","Prod1","Prod1","Prod1","Prod1"), Source = c("Point1","Point2","Point2","Point3","Point3"), Dest=c("Point2","Point3","Point4","Point4","Point2"))

dbPathWay <- data.frame()
# dbPathWay <- NULL  #data frame to save all possible paths. Repre
# dbProdDest <- data.frame()

#Find sources that are not destinations (initial points)
dbSources <-  (dbProdDest[!(dbProdDest$Source %in% dbProdDest$Dest),])

for (iSource in unique(dbSources$Source)){

    # Initialize a list to be used to append every step on the pathway
    newRowPathWay <- list("Case" = 99999, "Product" = "Prod1")

    iNewSource <- iSource
    #Recursive part
    dbPathWay <- GetDestinRecursive(dbProdDest, iNewSource, newRowPathWay, dbPathWay)

} # end
```

3. if (is.null(dbNewDest)) was changed with if (nrow(dbNewDest) == 0)
4. recursion function returns new dbPathWay - I made sure it is updated in the calling environment. Code:

   ```
   GetDestinRecursive <- function(dbProdDest, iNewSource,  newRowPathWay, dbPathWay){
       countDest <- as.character(length(newRowPathWay)-1)
       newRowPathWay[[countDest]] <- iNewSource

       dbNewDest <- dbProdDest[dbProdDest$Source == iNewSource,]

       #If there is no new destinations to iNewSource, so iNewSource is an end
       if (nrow(dbNewDest) == 0){
           #Append RowPathWay in dbPathWaty
           dfRow <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(newRowPathWay), ncol = length(newRowPathWay), byrow=F),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
           dbPathWay <- rbind.fill(dbPathWay , dfRow )
           return(dbPathWay)
       } else{
           #For each new destination, check if it is already a vertice in the pathway. If it is true, break the loop. Otherwise, call recursion
           for (iDest in dbNewDest$Dest){
               if (iDest %in% newRowPathWay){
                   dfRow <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(newRowPathWay), ncol = length(newRowPathWay), byrow=F),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
                   dbPathWay <- rbind.fill(dbPathWay , dfRow )  
               } else
               {
                   dbPathWay <- GetDestinRecursive(dbProdDest, iDest, newRowPathWay, dbPathWay )
               } #end if iDest
           } # end for iDest
       } # end if is.null
       return(dbPathWay )
   } #end GetDestinRecursive
   ```

The other option would be to just omit dbPathWay parameter and using <<- operator to fill the table:

```
GetDestinRecursive2 <- function(dbProdDest, iNewSource,  newRowPathWay){
    countDest <- as.character(length(newRowPathWay)-1)
    newRowPathWay[[countDest]] <- iNewSource

    dbNewDest <- dbProdDest[dbProdDest$Source == iNewSource,]

    #If there is no new destinations to iNewSource, so iNewSource is an end
    if (nrow(dbNewDest) == 0){
        #Append RowPathWay in dbPathWaty
        dfRow <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(newRowPathWay), ncol = length(newRowPathWay), byrow=F),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
        dbPathWay <<- rbind.fill(dbPathWay , dfRow )
        # return(dbPathWay)
    } else{
        #For each new destination, check if it is already a vertice in the pathway. If it is true, break the loop. Otherwise, call recursion
        for (iDest in dbNewDest$Dest){
            if (iDest %in% newRowPathWay){
                dfRow <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(newRowPathWay), ncol = length(newRowPathWay), byrow=F),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
                dbPathWay <<- rbind.fill(dbPathWay , dfRow )  
                # return(dbPathWay )
            } else
            {
                GetDestinRecursive2(dbProdDest, iDest, newRowPathWay )
            } #end if iDest
        } # end for iDest
    } # end if is.null

} #end GetDestinRecursive
```

In this case make sure that you do not assign the return of recursive function to dbPathWay, so call it that way

```
#Recursive part
GetDestinRecursive2(dbProdDest, iNewSource, newRowPathWay)
```

Comment: yes, I have another loop to make sure ProdDest has only one product.  I'm not sure if I understood your comment about "recursion function returns new dbPathWay - I made sure it is updated in the calling environment."   I changed the source code but it results only in first route.Using the example, dbPathWay contains only the  "99999   Prod1   Point1    Point2    Point3    Point4" register. Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried the code I provided? It works on my computer. Only the call to recursive function was missing dbPathWay parameter. I'll make an edit now

Comment: I changed my code following your code, but clearly I missed something because, now I deleted all my code and copied everything from yours and it worked.  Thanks, @h1427096